# Select highest profit from each year SQL

Tags: sql, select, sqlplus

How do I obtain the highest value for each year within a table. So let's say we have a table `movies` and I want to find the highest profiting film for each year.

This is my attempt so far:

```
SELECT year, MAX(income - cost) AS profit, title
FROM Movies m, Movies m2
GROUP BY year
```

I am pretty certain it is going to need some sub selects but I can't visualise what I need to do. I was also thinking probably some sort of `distinct` option to rule out duplicate  years.

```
Title  Year   Income  Cost  Length
A      2000   10      2     2
B      2000   9       7     2
```

So from this the expected result would be

```
Title  Year   Profit
A      2000   8
```

Comment: dude you have yourself answered your question. Or rather be a little more specific in what you want to achieve

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: Why are you using `Movies` twice, and not actually referencing aliases?

Comment: Do you need to know _which_ movie had the highest profit in each year?

Comment: What database are you using? Please tag your question with this.

Comment: Sorry so lets say there is a table Movies with title, year, cost, income, number. I want to obtain the highest profit(income-cost) of each movie and for each year. Displaying the profit, year and title.

Comment: Some sample data and a sample output would help massively.

Comment: Yeah I am terribly sorry for being so vague but I do not have the sample output or sample input. I can take a stab at it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing slightly at what you want, but since you've not specified any RDBMS a generic solution would be:

```
SELECT  m.Year, (m.Income - m.Cost) AS Profit, m.Title
FROM    Movies m
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  m.Year, MAX(m.Income - m.Cost) AS Profit
            FROM    Movies
            GROUP BY m.Year
        ) MaxProfit
            ON MaxProfit.Year = m.Year
            AND MaxProfit.Profit = (m.Income - m.Cost)
ORDER BY m.Year
```

You can also do this using analytic functions if your DBMS permits. e.g. SQL-Server

```
WITH MovieCTE AS
(   SELECT  m.Year,
            Profit = (m.Income - m.Cost), 
            m.Title,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.Year ORDER BY (m.Income - m.Cost) DESC)
    FROM    Movies
)
SELECT  year, Profit, Title
FROM    MovieCTE
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

It is possible I have misunderstood your exact criteria, but I am sure the same priciples can be applied, you will just need to alter the grouping and the join in the first example, or the `partition by` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m1year,m1profit,title 
from 
(
  (select year as m1year, max(income- cost) as m1profit from movies group by year) m1
   join
  (select m2year, (income-cost) as m2profit ,title as profit from movies) m2
   on 
   m1profit = m2profit
) m
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the highest profit movie for each year, and choose the first title in the event of a tie:

```
 select a.year, a.profit,
    (select min(title) from Movies where year = a.year and income - cost = a.profit) as title
 from ( 
     select year, max(income - cost) as profit
     from Movies -- title, year, cost, income, number
     group by year
) as a
order by year desc
```